# SSAS cube as data source

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL Server 2017.

There is a legacy application using SQL Server Analysis Services (Tabular mode) cube as a data source for its own calculations running DAX queries against it in WHILE cycle. This apparently takes several days to process.
Performance-wise, wouldn't it be faster to use this cube's Dimensions and Fact views as data source.

And if dwelling on the views, should I consider having them as indexed views (no indexes there historically).

EDIT: WHILE runs sp constructing DAX query to different dimensions based on the types of request and runs it to the table at the end. Usual sp iteration result is several thousand of rows.

```
SELECT * FROM 
                           OPENQUERY([DPServer],'EVALUATE
                   (
                       ADDCOLUMNS
                       (
                           SUMMARIZE
                           (
                           FILTER
                               (
                                   FILTER(
                                       ''vwFact_Global_2013'',
                                       RELATED(''Dim1''[Name])="Jalapeno"),RELATED(''Dim3''[Param3]) = "Green"),       
               ''Dim1''[Name],
               ''Dim2''[Country], 
               ''Dim2''[Param1], 
               ''Dim2''[Param2], 
               ''Dim3''[Param3],
               ''Dim3''[Param4],
               ''Dim3''[Param5],
               ''Dim3''[Param6],
               ''Dim3''[Comment], 
               ''Dim4''[Details], 
               ''Dim4''[Expanded_Info]
           ),
               "Count_Global_2013",CALCULATE([Count_Global_2013]),
               "CountW_Global_2013",CALCULATE([CountW_Global_2013])
           ))')
```

Thank you!

Comment: It depends! What are the calculations that are being run? What is the code for the views? How many rows of data are we talking about?

Comment: The code in the views joins 4 tables together.
The number of rows could be up to half a billion.

Comment: calculations are arithmetic formulae applying coefficients, calculating averages and sums based on the groups of ids.

Comment: Assuming a reasonable level of aggregation SSAS Tabular should typically be faster for those sorts of operations than SQL. That WHILE cycle may be the issue, it's almost always best to run one big query than iterate through lots of little ones.

Comment: Yes, WHILE was also my concern as well.

Comment: It may be best to edit the question sharing the DAX code of that query and how it's used within the loop.